# Cryptomatte node not displaying anything?

Tags: compositing-nodes, .exr, cryptomatte

I am not sure if a screenshot is needed. Basically, I have rendered a sequence in open EXR Multilayer 32 Bits.

When I import the files into a new Blender file in the compositor I can see the cryptomattes scrolling around the Main node (view layer). But when I use the cryptomatte node and plug the combined dot into the crypto matter does not show anything in the picker.

Do you know how can I solve this?

[image]

Thank you

[image]

[image]

Comment: @MartyFouts Done :)

Comment: Check the updated thread...There is what you are advising me..

Answer (score 1):

As you can see on the node, you have the choice between `Render` and `Image`, that is because the node works in different ways when you use a `Render Layer` node or an external image sequence.

So push down the `Image` button. Then you will have to manually load up the image sequence, manually set the `Frames` and `Start Frame` (just mimic what you have in the `Image Sequence` node)m and set the view layer drop down.

[image: example picture]

Also make sure you don't use DWAA compression for your EXR sequence, otherwise it will look like this:

[image: DWAA example picture]

Comment: Thank you so much....I used DWAA :(  Noooooo hahahha But then the 32 bits are extremely heavy for my hard disk . Thank you so much

Comment: Hi. I am trying your advice. Is not working. I loaded the EXR in the Cryptomatte node as an image sequence. I can see the masks, but I can not select the one I want by using the + button...nothing happens.

Comment: You have to switch to the Pick output in order to be able to select the matte IDs you need. Also, I said to avoid DWAA, but I didn't say to not use any compression. DWAA breaks passes, just use basically any other compression method, like Pxr24, that would work. DWAA is fine only for regular color/beauty output, not for data/passes.

Comment: Thank you, picking from masks was not working. I still find the cryptomatte a bit un-streamlined. Could be easier if the actual EXR multilayer allows to pick from that....instead of reloading again the same thing. I will try the other compressions :)

Comment: Ok I found out why was so hard for me to click on the masks. I do not use the backdrop feature. I use the image editor window showing the viewer node. Apparently the eyedrop does not work on that image. I guess I can not escape from using the backdrop feature.